# Equivalent of IFF in Case SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert an access IFF query to an SQL Server query

```
SELECT blah blah ,
    IIf([stock]![supplier]=[pos]![supplier],"Preferred"," ") AS Preferrednew 
FROM blah blah
```

In access this will give a value of preferred in a column called Preferrednew where the condition is true.

I have converted the code to..

```
SELECT blah blah ,
 CASE WHEN ([stock.supplier] = [pos.supplier]), 'test', 'test2' AS [preferrednew]
FROM blah blah
```

but I get the error

> Incorrect syntax near ','

What is the correct format ?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT blah blah ,
    CASE WHEN stock.supplier = pos.supplier THEN 'test'
    ELSE 'test2'
    END AS [preferrednew]
FROM blah blah
```

Keep in mind that SQL Server 2012+ supports **[`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)**

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Yes I tried IIF but we are pre 2012 - when we upgrade the database will case still work ?

Comment: @Emma CASE will work of course, IIF is just syntactic sugar :)

Comment: Thanks again for your swift help :)

Comment: Thanks for noting that `IIF` is supported since SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Emma If this post is helpful, consider marking as answer ;)